# Creating a fake request to render a view to a string in django

Tags: python, django

**Problem**

I'd like to render an arbitrary view, by calling the view (capture the response and extract the rendered content), to a string, inside another view.
The problem being I'd like to have a dummy user "logged-in" during the rendering of that view, along with changing a few other minor things in the request.
What I'd like to avoid is building a request completely from scratch, as 90% of the request I'll have at hand in the parent view will be the same.

I'm wondering how I should go about this as far as best practice is concerned, as well as technically?

I'm currently thinking something like this: (But I can't help but feel this is horrible and there's got to be a better way, I just cannot think of it)

> View stuff...
>
> Log current user out
>
> Create/Login dummy user
>
> Somehow modify request a bit
>
> Render view to string
>
> Log out dummy user
>
> Log back in original user
>
> End of view stuff...

Any ideas? Or a pointer into a better direction?

Thanks,
dennmat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually need to log the current user out, you could just change the user in the [`HttpRequest`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest) object you plan to use to render the other view. You could do something like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.http import HttpResponse

def view_inside_a_view(request):
    return HttpResponse('hello %s' % request.user)

def view(request):
    # change to dummy user, or whoever
    request.user = User.objects.get(id=1)
    response = view_inside_a_view(request)
    return HttpResponse('rendered view: %s' % response.content)
```

If you need to login your dummy user you could use [`django.contrib.auth.authenticate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.authenticate) or or [`django.contrib.auth.login`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.login) to do so. Example using `login` (avoids necessity of using dummy user's password):

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import login, get_backends
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.http import HttpResponse

@login_required
def view_inside_a_view(request):
    return HttpResponse('hello %s' % request.user)

def view(request):
    # login dummy user
    user = User.objects.get(id=2)
    backend = get_backends()[0]
    user.backend = "%s.%s" % (backend.__module__, backend.__class__.__name__)
    login(request, user)
    # change request's user
    request.user = user
    # get response from view
    response = view_inside_a_view(request)
    return HttpResponse('rendered view: %s' % response.content)
```

Comment: Would that user not then fail authentication tests within the views? I unfortunately am un-able to use an AnonymousUser for this.

Comment: You can use your dummy user instead. I changed my example to switch the user to an arbitrary one.

Comment: Would is_authenticated return True in this case? Or would I have to log the dummy user in for that? Or is there a way I could trick or temporarily confuse is_authenticated to return True throughout my 'views_inside_a_view' calls?

Comment: You could use [`authenticate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.authenticate) to authenticate manually.

Comment: So the logging in was required, I stored the original user and then logged them out, before login in the 'dummy' user, I then do the inverse before returning in the view and it gets the job done, I sort of want to write up a little helper class to make tinkering with stuff like this a little easier and clearer. If I do I'll put it up. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Depending upon how much you're relying on getting information from the request during the view, it might be best that you just create a function to do all of the view's dirty work, and have your real view just pass in the values it needs into this function. So, instead of a view function that takes a request, create another function that takes a user:

```
def _real_view(user):
    return render_to_response('template.html', {'user' : user})

def view(request):
    # Now both of these are possible...
    response = _real_view(User.objects.get(5))
    response = _real_view(request.user)
    return response
```

Then, when you want to a view using a different user, you only need to grab the information for that user and pass it into the view. No need to change the current user or modify the request at all.

Comment: This could be a solution and would work, unfortunately what I'm trying to accomplish will be calling a large variety of already existing views, and would be too intrusive on the current system. Thank you though.

Comment: +1: Good suggestion.  @dennmat: "would be too intrusive". False.  Refactoring is easy.  Write unit tests.  Refactor.  Don't mess around with views calling views.  Get it right.

Comment: @S.Lott - Changing the design of your existing system to bend over for one task is not getting it right. This solution is good for something dedicated to this functionality. Currently I am using Controllers for my views, which are classes that are initialized with the request, the views are methods of these classes. This creates more of an mvc type structure than purely method based views, it also takes away a lot of the overhead, as in a metaclass manages urls, decorates can be class wide etc... For my purpose it needs to be done from inside a function and be as unobtrusive as possible.

Comment: @dennmat: I always thought that correctly refactoring was getting it right.  Your saying that a good design isn't somehow right?  "the views are methods of these classes" doesn't change the idea that two view methods can share a common underlying method.  Or share a free-floating function.  Or a view method and a free-floating REST function can share a common function.  "unobtrusive as possible" means refactoring to result in unobtrusive in the long run.  The long run design is the only thing that matters.

Comment: @S.Lott I see what you're saying I do, and generally I'd agree. However, in this scenario, this is only needed in one spot, not for every view, only specific views, and is in the big picture a very small portion of the system. Therefore I feel creating "mothering" functions for every view, not only adds a function call to the heap on any request instead of just for the times they get called from this function(as these views can still be accessed regularly); it just doesn't seem worth the overhead and extra work later, for all those views, especially when the current design works well as it is

Comment: I highly doubt that an additional function call is going to increase the overhead in your system enough to notice. However, the real issue here is whether or not you have enough time to create and test the required changes. Most likely, that answer is "no", which is fine. We don't all have the opportunity to create the perfect system.

Comment: @Mark +1 That is a big part, it would be a sizeable change at this point. And the one function call wouldn't create a lot of overhead, but if you say that about everything eventually there's lots of overhead. I'm also modifying more than just the user before calling the views. It's definitely a valid solution and a good solution and I appreciate the answer. Thanks :)

Comment: @dennmat: "this is only needed in one spot, not for every view, only specific views".  Then refactor those and nothing more.

Answer (score 1):

just use the test client - it's not only good for testing:

```py
from django.test import Client

c = Client()
# login if necessary
c.login(username='dummy', password='user')
# get the view
response = c.get(reverse('my-view', args=[foo,bar])
html = response.content
```

Since 1.6 this is even officially documented, however it works in older versions too: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/testing/tools/#module-django.test.client